# I need help on IF EXIST ELSE

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I need help on this line

```
string query = @"IF EXISTS(Select * From u_Data Where TAG = '" + txtTag.Text + "') begin Update u_data set Name = '" + txtNama.Text +
                "', NIK = '" + txtNIK.Text + "', Department = '" + txtDept.Text + "' where Tag = '" + txtTag.Text +
                "' end else begin Insert Into u_data (TAG, Name, NIK, Department) VALUES ('" + txtTag.Text + "', '" + txtNama.Text + "', '" + txtNIK.Text + "', '" + txtDept.Text + "') end";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
```

Cannot Update at all &
will only insert

Comment: Try running the same query in SQL management studio with appropriate values. Does it run successfully there?

Comment: Bobby Tables just asked to add the department `');drop table department;--`.  But I somehow doubt his sincerity? Btw, there exists also a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement for upserts.

Answer (score 2):

Running such a query may leads to **[`SQL INJECTION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)**

You should

- use **parameters** in your query-
- create a single query that handles the `IF EXISTS()` part *on the server*

Try this code:

```
    string query = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM u_Data WHERE TAG = @Tag)
                        UPDATE u_data SET NIK = @Nik, Department = @Department 
                        WHERE TAG = @Tag
                        ELSE
                        INSERT INTO u_Data (TAG, Name, NIK, Department) VALUES(@Tag, @Name, @Nik, @Department);";

    //create connection and command in "using" blocks
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tag", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtTag.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nik", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtNIK.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtDept.Text;
        // open connection, execute query, close connection
        conn.Open();
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate. Easy and clean.